# Create method to calculate a field in the Domain or in the Service

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

If we have a Class Book and we want to calculate the score of a Book following some rules like "if the number of pages is lower than X then we need to substract Y from the score" and using an Hexagonal Architecture. Should we place this method calculateScore() in a separate Service in case this logic changes in the future using different fields or this reponsibility should be in the Domain itself?

**1st approach**

```
package com.xxx.domain;

[...]
public class Book {

    [...]

    public Double score() {
        [...]
    }

    [...]

}
```

**2nd approach**

```
package com.xxx.application;

[...]
public interface ScoreService {

    [...]

    void calculateScore(Book book);

    [...]

}
```

Comment: It would depend on what you want to do with the score.  Is it for client view (report) only? 
 Is it something to be calculated and persisted with the book?  Some other purpose?  A little more background would be required to give the best feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Calculated and persisted with the Book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should we place this method calculateScore() in a separate Service in case this logic changes in the future using different fields or this reponsibility should be in the Domain itself?

First the clean architecture is very clear when it comes to the question "Where should business logic be placed?".

- Application agnostic business logic in the entities layer.
- Application specific business logic in the use case layer.

But I think your question is about something a bit different, it's about [anemic or rich domain models](https://link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/10/01/anemic-vs-rich-domain-models/). I can't tell you every of my thoughts here, but I have written down most of them in the blog I linked in the sentence before.

The condensed statement of mine is

> rich domain models combine data and logic while anemic models separate them.

Let's think about the anemic way...

If you place the logic in a separate service it usually means that you have to expose all properties of the book. You will make them public or at least package scope if the service is in the same package.

Your question also focuses on *change*. You make the statement that logic changes can be better handled if the logic is put in a separate service. That's true, but it comes at a cost.

It's true that an anemic model let you add logic easier, but it is also true that each logic (each service) must have the same interpretation of the anemic model. I mean each service must know how to modify the data structure properly to keep it consistent and that will be hard to maintain when the number of services grows.

But implementing the service can also be a good intermediate step, because it will give you a hint about cohesion. The cohesion usually shows you where to place a method. E.g.

```
public class ScoreService {

    public BookScore calculateScore(Book book, BookRentals rentals){
        int pageCount = book.getPageCount();
        Author author = book.getAuthor();

        // calculate a new value based on pageCount and the author
        // ...

        OtherValue ov = book.getSomeOtherValue();
        // do something with ov

        int rentalCount = rentals.getCountSince(someDate);
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

When you look at the `calculateScore` above you will recognize that there are a lot of `get` invocations on `Book` and less on `BookRentals`. This is a hint that most of the data that `calculateScore` needs is placed in the `Book`. Thus the `calculateScore`'s cohesion is higher to `Book` and the method might be placed in the `Book`class. E.g.

```
public class Book {

    public BookScore getScore(BookRentals rentals){
        int pageCount = this.getPageCount();
        Author author = this.getAuthor();

        // calculate a new value based on pageCount and the author
        // ...

        OtherValue ov = this.getSomeOtherValue();
        // do something with ov

        int rentalCount = rentals.getCountSince(someDate);
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

The difference is obvious:

1. the number of method parameters decreases. Maybe you apply DDD and `Book` is an aggregation root and also has access to `BookRentals`. Then your parameters might decrease to zero.
2. Since most of the properties that `getScore` needs are located in the `Book` class, you might want to lower their visibilily to private. So that uncontrolled access is not allowed.

One question that often arises when developers put the logic in the entities is: "How can an entity access data from a data store?"

My solution is to just pass a repository to the methods that need it. E.g.

```
public class Book {

    public BookScore getScore(BookRentalRepository repo){
        // ...
        int rentalCount = repo.getRentalCountSince(this, someDate);
    }
}
```

Whatever way you want to go, anemic or rich, keep the logic in a POJO. Also keep in mind that a [POJO can be more than a simple data structure](https://link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/09/26/the-difference-between-pojos-and-java-beans/).

I hope my answer helps you to make a decision for your specific application.

Answer (score 1):

If the calc of the score depends only on the book state, i would create a method in the book entity to calc it.

Otherwise, if it depends on other domain objects also, i would create a domain service for calculating it.

Regarding to persist the score. I would persist it just if the calc process is very complicated and takes a lot of time. Otherwise,  I wouldn't persist it and calc it when need it.

In case you persist jt, you have to consider that you have to recalculate it and persist the new value every time the other values it depends on change too.

Comment: And what about if you need to calculate something over a list of books? Is it also domain service? Is the usecase just acting as orchestrator of repo requests?

Comment: In that case, it would depend on what are you calculating, is it a concept belonging to the domain? Then it should be calc by a domain service. App services are just for orchestrating domain operations.